# clisp : remove from list of list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

`(remove '(1 2) '((1 2) (1 3)))`
doesn't remove `'(1 2)` from list in common lisp. (I think it uses `eq` and not `equal`).
 Do we have any other alternative to delete element from list of lists in common lisp?

Comment: The default test for most functions is EQL. You can provide your own in many cases with the :TEST keyword parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(remove '(1 2) '((1 2) (1 3)) :test #'equal)
```